# HTML CSS: Adding in new lines

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am following the tutorial/code described [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/design-bootstrap-django-python-tutorial/). The specific code in question is this part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Harrison Kinsley</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
          height:100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:95%; ">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <br>
                  <center>
                    <img src="{% static 'personal/img/profile.jpg' %}" class="responsive-img" style='max-height:100px;' alt="face">
                  </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <br>
                  <center>
                  <h3>Programming, Teaching, Entrepreneurship</h3>
                  </center>
              </div>
        </div><hr>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
          <br>

          <br>
           <!-- Great, til you resize. -->
            <!--<div class="well bs-sidebar affix" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">-->
            <div class="well bs-sidebar" id="sidebar" style="background-color:#fff">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href='/contact/'>Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div> <!--well bs-sidebar affix-->
          </div> <!--col-sm-2-->
          <div class="col-sm-10">

            <div class='container-fluid'>
            <br><br>
               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}   
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid" style='margin-left:15px'>
            <p><a href="#" target="blank">Contact</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">LinkedIn</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Twitter</a> | <a href="#" target="blank">Google+</a></p>
        </div>
    </footer>   

</body>

</html>
```

When I run this code, the links to 'Home', Blog' and 'Content' pages are all on one line, with no spaces between them (i.e. the links are like this: HomeBlogContent).

I want them to look like:

```
Home
Blog
Content
```

When I add this line into the code:

```
<p>This is<br>a paragraph<br>with line breaks</p>
```

The output is as expected:

```
This is
a paragraph
with line breaks
```

When I replace the strings in this line, like this:

```
<p><li><a href='/'>Home</a></li><br>li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li><br>li><a href='/contents/'>Contents</a></li></p>
```

I would have hoped that solved my problem, but it doesn't. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong, how can I get the Home, Blog and Content links to print on separate lines? Thanks.

Comment: some of this is invalid HTML: `</li><br>li>`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the left bracket for your `<li>` tags.

Or if you're not a noob just get rid of those `<br>` tags. `<li>` will go to next line automatically.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href='/'>Home</a>
  <a href='/blog/'>Blog</a>
  <a href='/contents/'>Contents</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: he needs to use `<ul>` instead of  `<p>`  then add `<ul style="list-style-type:none;">` if he wants no bullets

Comment: Right needs a <ul>. I edited answer to what he should actually do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup looks good to me in the original file. However, from the problem you are describing sounds like there is something wrong with how you are importing Bootstrap 3 into this file. Check that you have the file `bootstrap.min.css` where you say you have it under `personal/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href='/contents/'>Contents</a></li>
</ul>
```